# Wordpress logo not displaying on only on chrome desktop

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, graphical-logo

even after updating the code below, Logo still not showing on desktop.

```
.pro_logo a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

1. Website=> trinitech.in
2. Logo => trinitech.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Trinitech_Blue_V1.svg
3. No logo Issue in mobile. But In my android mobile, when I switch to Desktop Site, again the logo disappears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting the width of the parent (anchor tag) to 100%.
`.header__titles a { width: 100%;}`

Comment: Brilliant! thanks much! it worked instantly

Comment: You're welcome. I'll post as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this

```css
.pro_logo a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height :auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the parent (anchor tag) to 100%

```
.header__titles a 
{ 
    width: 100%;
}
```